# Word Detection and change it to Voice ..Like R ..Then Speak R

Tags: android, media, voice

I have a idea to make an application but i got stuck in between. I want that i can write any letter on android screen by using finger scroll. And now i want to listen from android device that what i have written on the screen of android.

Let I have write R by touching screen now i want to listen the pronunciation   of that R as Human voice.
Hope you all understand my problem

Comment: So? where's your problem _exactly_?

Comment: i have no idea about how to achieve it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the GestureOverlay to get the right characters that are written.
Take a look over [here](http://developer.android.com/resources/articles/tts.html) for the text to speech functionality

Comment: First thanx for quick reply Dezentje. i will go through your link

Comment: Thank you T Denzente your answer help me a lot,,so im  accepting it as a answer